# Let's clean up some meta tags

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

First, let's look at the advice from [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

> ### Avoid meta-tags
>
> Do not use [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in questions. Here are some tips
> to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>
> - **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a
>   meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as
>   the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`,
>   and `[best-practices]`, are not helpful by themselves – they do not
>   communicate anything about the content of the question.
> - **If the tag
>   commonly means different things to different people, it's probably a
>   meta-tag.** For example, the meaning of the tag `[subjective]` is, itself,
>   subjective; the same is true for tags like `[best-practices]` and
>   `[beginner]`. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? Use
>   only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective definition.

Let's, for now, focus only on the first bit of advice. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.**

Here is a list of likely candidates (those marked with a strikethrough currently have no questions using them):

- [delete](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete) - The very definition of a meta tag. Runs the whole gamut.
- <s>[editing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing)</s> - Useless without other tags. Useless generally. Presumably about changing something in a specific web app, which should already be a tag on the question. No one is an expert on "editing" on all web apps.
- <s>[filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter)</s>  - Can't possibly work as the only tag on a question. I see it used for [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (it should be [gmail-filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-filters)), [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets), [yahoo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) (which should be [yahoo-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail)), [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) comments. This also seems to run afoul of the second point above (it means different things to different people).
- [photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) - This can't possibly work as the only tag on a question. It needs to be paired with a web app. On the first page of questions I see [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), [google-plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus), [instagram](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram), [twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter), [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail), [dropbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dropbox). [facebook-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-photos) and [google-plus-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-photos) exist, at least.
- [url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) - Again, this has no context *without* the existence of other tags.
- <s>[web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web)</s> - What could this possibly even mean? Most of the questions tagged are closed. The rest look like web development questions or network protocol curiosity that should also be closed.
- <s>[syntax](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)</s>
- [syntax-highlighting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)
- [font](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font)
- [text-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting)
- <s>[color](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)</s>

So, how should we manage these? This is a problem and it seems to be getting worse. ("Broken windows" and all that.) Should we have a canonical "help clean up these meta-tags" question/answer, or should each individual one get its own question/answer (and arguments)?

There are also some other problematic tags that I think border on meta-tags, but will be harder to justify removing. (For instance, [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), based on its wiki, is for any webmail service that doesn't already have a tag. Not that it's used that way, of course.)

---

See also:

- [Can't make the [connections]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3969)

Comment: I think it's fine to keep these tag issues in one question.  People can always add additional ones below as answers which can be voted on.

Comment: Super User seems to go a few different ways on this (some proposals focusing on one tag or another, or a whole category of them at a time).

Comment: Looks to me that `google` is used sometimes as meta-tag. See [Please don't double tag Google items](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/540/please-dont-double-tag-google-items)

Comment: @Rubén: That's covered by [a separate discussion](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/540/please-dont-double-tag-google-items) although [not everyone agrees that "google" should generally be removed as a tag](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2495/why-are-more-general-tags-getting-removed-from-questions).

Comment: [Super User has a similar problem](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2125/can-we-get-rid-of-the-company-tags).

Comment: @AI E [Please don't double tag Google items](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/540/please-dont-double-tag-google-items) sounds to me as a "light request" while this discussion sounds to me as a "call to action". By the other hand, I agree that `google` should not be generally removed as a tag just in certain cases that it's used with other tags like `google-search` but there is no evident reason for including both of them.

Comment: Well, it's worth a separate discussion, I think, and shouldn't be glommed on to this one.

Comment: [tag:blog] is in a similar situation than [tag:email], I think.

Comment: Other tags to add to the list [tag:syntax], [tag:syntax-highlighting]

Comment: More tags to add to the list [tag:color], [tag:font], [tag:text-formatting]

Comment: More tags... [tag:text (34 questions)], [tag:user-interface] (57 questions), [tag:subtitles] (40 questions)

Answer (score 5):

I have cleaned up the [themes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/themes) & [history](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tags.  I will continue on my mission to clean up these tags.

This is a marathon not a race...

Answer (score 4):

Semi-abusing this as an update/call-to-action, **tl;dr: burninate [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter), [delete](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete)** now, clean up a single question then **also [url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url)**.

## `filter` (obsolete, see [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5150/88163))

Virtually nobody can be an expert on [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter)-ing in the abstract. Are we filtering results from [amazon](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon) to [zapier](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zapier)? The process is bound to be radically different (or [impossible, gee-thanks Amazon](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4209/how-do-i-look-at-just-the-reviews-of-the-format-im-buying-on-amazon)).

There are currently **70** questions tagged [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter). None of them are **only** tagged filter. Counts of the most common other tag on those questions (among those tagged filter...):

```
tag                  count
--------------------------
google-sheets           42
twitter                  5
gmail                    4
google-search            3
spam-prevention          2
yahoo-mail               2
search                   2
google-apps              1
google-sheets-query      1
regex                    1
netflix                  1
youtube                  1
outlook.com              1
amazon                   1
firefox-extensions       1
google-reader            1
rss                      1
```

Maybe [google-sheets-filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-filter) would be in order, but I think we can immediately remove and salt [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter).

Workbook: https://gist.github.com/nicktimko/f535fdcc14e06983454bdaecf053e564

---

## `delete`

There are currently **45** questions tagged [delete](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delete). None of them are **only** tagged delete. Counts of the most common other tag on those questions:

```
tag                  count
--------------------------
facebook                10
gmail                   10
trello                   5
google-drive             4
account-management       3
online-storage           1
pocket                   1
google-sites             1
facebook-groups          1
youtube                  1
google-apps-script       1
retweet                  1
yahoo-mail               1
gmail-labels             1
trello-boards            1
dropbox                  1
wiki                     1
screenshot               1
```

Again, how you delete something (beyond "click the trash icon" as step 1) is going to vary wildly.

---

## `url`

There are currently **104** questions tagged [url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url). [Only one is **only** tagged url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17059/in-web-urls-including-facebook-i-see-the-string-appearing-what-is-the-purp), and it likely doesn't belong here (it was migrated) as it's actually about URLs in the abstract, just with a Facebook URL as an example. Counts of the most common other tag on those other questions:

```
tag                       count
-------------------------------
youtube                      10
google-search                 9
google-sheets                 8
links                         7
facebook                      5
gmail                         5
google-plus                   5
google-drive                  4
search                        4
url-shortening                4
google-sites                  3
google-analytics              2
google-docs                   2
openstreetmap                 2
quora                         2
twitter                       2
amazon                        1
blog                          1   # probably another awful tag
blogger                       1
browser                       1
buffer                        1
evernote                      1
feeds                         1
github                        1
google-apps                   1
google-books                  1
google-calendar               1
google-chrome-extensions      1
google-fonts                  1
google-image-search           1
google-reader                 1
google-voice                  1
ical                          1
images                        1
linkedin                      1
microsoft-word                1
screenshot                    1
trello                        1
trello-cards                  1
typepad                       1
upload                        1
video                         1
website                       1
wetransfer                    1
```

Comment: We already have [tag:gmail-filters]. Cleaned questions with \[ [tag:gmail] [tag:filter] ].

Answer (score 1):

## `comments`

As of October 25, I think that this [comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) needs its own question to discuss some tags that already exist [facebook-comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-comments) and [google-drive-comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-comments).

I do not have a date in mind about when I might create a post to discuss this, but I created one for a tag in a similar situation but with a "worse" state regarding the number of tags having the same term : [What to do with [*search*]? Review of tag naming practices in Web Applications SE for tags using "search"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5144/88163)

---

### Old content

I cleaned up [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs)[comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) by removing [comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) There was 8 questions with both tags.

There is still a lot of work to do as is shown in the "related tags" (it will take some time (1 day?) for the system to update the related tags).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## `filter`

Has been cleaned up.