# Can't make the [connections]

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to the tag [connections](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connections).

Ten questions (at the moment). No usage guidance or wiki description.

About half of the questions are about LinkedIn connections. The rest are about network connections, Google+ connections, and a CW question for how to diagnose "when and why a website is down".

This would seem to be a meta tag. It has no context without other tags; it means different things to different people. Its primary usage (LinkedIn connections) seems to be adequately covered by using [linkedin](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linkedin).

I think this tag should be burninated. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree with the [tag:connections] burnination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there seems to be nothing but agreement, I've removed that tag from all of the questions where it existed (and cleaned up other things while I was there).

Now we just need to wait for the *Roomba* to come through and remove the tag altogether.