# Can we add "Do not use" to tags being cleaned-up since 2014?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags, tag-clean-up

On [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163) there is a list of tags that look as meta-tags but  after 6 years they are still "alive" (tags with `<s></s>` were not included):

> - [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) - Can't possibly work as the only tag on a question. I see it used for [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (it should be [gmail-filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-filters)),
>   [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets), [yahoo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) (which should be
>   [yahoo-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail)), [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) comments. This also seems to run
>   afoul of the second point above (it means different things to
>   different people).
> - [photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) - This can't possibly work as the only tag on a question. It needs to be paired with a web app. On the first page of
>   questions I see [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), [google-plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus), [instagram](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram),
>   [twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter), [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail), [dropbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dropbox). [facebook-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-photos) and
>   [google-plus-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-photos) exist, at least.
> - [url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url) - Again, this has no context *without* the existence of other tags.
>   questions or network protocol curiosity that should also be closed.
> - [syntax](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)
> - [syntax-highlighting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)
> - [text-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting)

Could we add to their tag excerpt **DO NOT USE THIS TAG** and a link to the above question in the tag wiki?

I.E.

[url](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url)

Tag excerpt

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG : Uniform Resource Locator or Universal Resource Locator - a specific character string that constitutes a reference to an Internet resource.

Tag wiki

> To learn why this tag should not be used please read [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163)

Comment: I hope that tag warnings will be used more often if/when this is implemented: [Give moderators the power to add tag warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338875). Currently marked status-review. (Many users will not notice the tag-info, but the tag-warning seem to be a bit more visible. However, at the moment they can only be added by Stack Exchange staff.)

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the tags can be blacklisted - which would prevent new question from being added to those tags. Since I do not want to repeat all technical details, I will add links to some post on other metas, where I wrote a bit more about this: [Can we please have a “deprecated tag” feature?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28025) and [The existing deprecated tags should be blacklisted](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3718).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we already have tags with "do not use":

- [browser](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser)
  DO NOT USE THIS TAG: If you have a generic problem with your browser, ask it on Super User; if you have a question about how a specific browser (e.g. Chrome) interacts with a web application, use that browser's own tag.
- [bookmarklet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookmarklet)
  DO NOT USE. Bookmarklets are no longer on-topic on Web Applications.
- [copyright](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright)
  DO NOT USE as this is a meta-tag. A legal concept, enacted by most governments, giving the creator of an original work exclusive rights to it, usually for a limited time.
- [migrate-data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data)
  DO NOT USE as this is a meta-tag. The moving of data either between two accounts on a service or between services. Normally asked about a service's default functionality.

So I think that is fair to say, **yes, we can**.

Related

- [search in tag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320083/289691)