# Why is the Text-Formatting tag actively discouraged?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently submitted a question on ruler lines in Google Docs.  One of the tags I thought appropriate was [text-formatting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-formatting).  But the tag description starts, "Do NOT use this tag" then describes what text formatting is, but does not explain why the tag isn't to be used.

Could the tag keepers please elucidate?

Comment: Related [Can we add “Do not use” to tags being cleaned-up since 2014?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4751/88163)

Comment: Thank you for checking the tag description before using.  So many users just blindly add tags.