# Why does [tag:filter] say "DO NOT USE THIS TAG"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-clean-up

- Tag [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) begins with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG", but it has a useful description and 77 associated questions that *do* use it.
- Tag [filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filters) has no description and no questions.

I don't have any immediate need for either tag, but something looks like it needs to be cleaned up there.

Comment: Welcome to Meta. [tag:filters] is a synomym of [tag:filter].  What is the confusion about these tags? P.S. Here is a link to a related Q/A https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163..

Comment: @Rubén, If `filters` is a synonym for `filter`, it would be very helpful if it had a description saying exactly that. ¶ But the real question is, what is the point of having a tag whose description begins by shouting at me that I shouldn't use it?

Answer (score 1):

[filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) has "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" because in this site it's considered a meta-tag.  From [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163):

> - [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) - Can't possibly work as the only tag on a question. I see it used for [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) (it should be [gmail-filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-filters)), [google-spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets), [yahoo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo)[email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) (which should be [yahoo-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-mail)), [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube) comments. This also seems to run afoul of the second point above (it means different things to different people).

The above link also invites the community to participate on the meta-tag clean up and includes advice about how to do it.

Related

- [Can we add "Do not use" to tags being cleaned-up since 2014?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4751/88163)